# Vuforia - Crop the Image/Texture2D from camera device

Tags: vuforia, texture2d

I have some questions for the feature:
First:
I want to get the video from the physical camera without any virtual object.
I use the code:

```
Vuforia.Image resultImg = CameraDevice.Instance.GetCameraImage(mPixelFormat);
```

This method will return a Vuforia.Image, and the resultImg provide a method called CopyToTexture, and it will cause the screen freeze for a while(user will see the incoherence).

And another method cannot get readable texture2D:

```
VuforiaRenderer.Instance.VideoBackgroudTexture;
```

Second:
   How to crop a textured2d by a rect? Or How to  get 500*500 pixels or texture2d (not full screen) in picture which is caught by physical camera.

This two question have torment me for 2 weeks, and there few document to refer, thank you if you give me some advise.

Comment: Do you work with unity ?

Comment: yes, I am working with unity.

Comment: Could you give me some advise?

Answer (score 0):

For the first question you could use the code below

```
    RenderTexture rt = new RenderTexture(resWidth, resHeight, 24);
    GetComponent<Camera>().targetTexture = rt;
    Texture2D screenShot = new Texture2D(resWidth, resHeight, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    GetComponent<Camera>().Render();
    RenderTexture.active = rt;
    screenShot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, resWidth, resHeight), 0, 0);
    GetComponent<Camera>().targetTexture = null;
    RenderTexture.active = null;
    Destroy(rt);
```

This code allows you to take a screenshot from the camera and stock it in the Texture2D **screenShot**. This doesn't cause the screen to freeze and the texture2D is completly readable.

I do not have the answer for your second question but I guess you should crop the image before converting it to Texture2D.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and the code you provide can get the camera object for stage, not the physical camera device, right? The feature I want to implemented is to get the **pysical camera picture** without virtual object on screen, and also I need to get a center crop rect for this picture. Is there a better way to finish it?

Comment: And if you want to implement a QR code scanner by vuforia, and it will work when the QR code is scanned in a blue rect area?  How do you coding for this function?